# How to put two elements in the same sequence?

Tags: constraint-programming, opl, cp-optimizer

I want to force the flexible job shop example model in CP Optimizer that if a specific mode/element is put in a sequence the successor has to be put also in the same sequence which means in this case that both have to be done on the same machine. How can I create such an subject to condition??
Thank you in advance for your help!!

```
dvar sequence mchs[m in Mchs] in all(md in Modes: md.mch == m) modes[md]

minimize max(j in Jobs, o in Ops: o.pos==jlast[j]) endOf(ops[o]);
subject to {....}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `op_1` and `op_2` denote the two operations that must be allocated to the same machine and if `mode_1_i` and `mode_2_i` denote the optional interval variables representing the allocation of `op_1` (resp. `op_2`) on machine `i`, then all you need to do is posting a constraint: `presenceOf(mode_1_i)==presenceOf(mode_2_i)`.